# Haskell lists difference

Tags: haskell

I'm trying make a lists difference. Found directly prelude operator `\\\\` that makes lists difference. But errors `Not in scope: '\\\\'` occurs. Here is my simple from command line interpreter:

```
Prelude>  ([1,2,3] ++ [5,6])   -- works like expected
[1,2,3,4,5,6]

prelude>  ([1,2,3] \\\\ [1,2])   -- erros occurs
<interactive>:1:11: Not in scope: "\\\\"
```

Thanks for explanation where I make a mistake.

Answer (score 47):

It's `\\`, not `\\\\`. You also need to `import Data.List`.

```
Prelude List> import Data.List
Prelude List> ([1,2,3] \\ [1,2])
[3]
```

Comment: Or with hierarchical modules, `import Data.List`.  (Although in GHCi, you need to use `:module + Data.List` instead.)

Comment: wow! It's a discovery for me that you can just `Prelude> import Data.List` in ghci. I always used `:m +Data.List`

Comment: @max taldykin, although unrelated, you might also enjoy `:set prompt ">>> "`, or whatever string you like.  I get to the point where the list of modules I have imported takes up a whole line of my console, which is no fun.

Comment: This is not working when you `import Data.Set`. Any workaround on that?

Comment: `(\\)` is ambiguous when you import both `Data.List` and `Data.Set`. There are multiple solutions. You can for example use `import qualified Data.Set` or you can hide the set version of `(\\)` by using `import Data.Set hiding ((\\))`. See [haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Import) for more details on imports.